# How to trigger watchkit app from the parent iphone app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, watchkit, apple-watch

Is there a way to open a WatchKit app programmatically from the host iPhone app?

If this is not supported, can I trigger a local notification that shows up on Apple Watch and tapping it would open the corresponding WatchKit app?

Comment: Thanks Florian, I appreciate this

Answer (score 4):

You cannot open the WatchKit extension from the iOS app. The only way to alert the user on the Watch is to send a remote or local notification. However, this will not work if your iOS app is in the foreground because the notification will simply route to the iPhone and not the Watch.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was going to say

Comment: @cnoon  & TheCodingArt, 

 This is the reverse action which you are talking about, 
I know how to open host iOS application from watchkit in background.

What I need is to open Watch Application from parent iOS
App programatically.

Comment: @Chetan, there's no way to do what you're asking, nor should you try. Apple is very keen on logic should be pulled and performed via the parent application and the apple watch application should be treated as an extension. The Apple Watch application should be modular and only execute when the user interacts with it. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/DesigningaWatchKitApp.html

Comment: Thanks all for answer,

Comment: If you feel the answer is sufficient, then you should upvote and mark as such when you get a chance. Cheers.